# Way to Refresh Network Drives due to Disconnection from Pending VPN Connection without Workflow Interruption

Tags: batch-file, cmd, vpn, network-drive

Most of my company is currently working from home and is having to tunnel into our office network through a VPN. As such, all our network drives are, technically, disconnected until we login to the VPN. Once connected, we could simply open a file explorer window and open each network drive to reestablish/refresh the connection in Windows' eyes, but more than 2 or 3 drives is a hassle, and some of our members don't even think to do this every day even for our main project drive (only universal drive letter we use in our office) before opening some of our programs that need a network drive mapped, and thus have the potential to mess up our files or link therein.

Desired Solution:
I'm looking for a batch or cmd file that can run to refresh or reconnect the drives, without explicitly using `NET USE` if possible (more on why further down) or opening a file explorer by using a batch file to open a shortcut to a network folder. If this just isn't possible, I'll stick with the solution I have that uses `NET USE`, but would appreciate help smoothing out the issues outlined below.

I have a couple solutions that are more than a little intrusive in that they require some form of interaction to dismiss them once launched, rather than running, reaching eof, then closing using `TIMEOUT /T 5`. I was hoping there might be something a little more streamlined, or at least less intrusive, that I could use to avoid these unnecessary interactions that I'm currently dealing with:

- Shortcut to a folder on each drive to "ping" said drive for refresh, but this opens a file explorer window, potentially interrupting workflow. I would like to suppress this window opening if possible, or at least immediately close it (not exactly how file explorer works, I know).
- Batch file that tests all mapped drives for disconnected ones, then attempts to reconnect, sometimes causing a user input in the cmd window to interrupt workflow (We have two security levels each with their own login credentials, and several of us have mapped network drives using each of the two creds, so some disconnected drives will require manual entry of username and password when the `/USER:%username% %password%` parameters don't work, which I just can't seem to avoid. Neither server nor network location for `NET USE` are viable tests for which security level, as their labeled after the project itself rather than the security level needed, and so my only remedy here would be to suppress the asking for user input).
- Multiple batch files, one for each drive, requiring users to manually copy and alter batch files for their own needs (only one drive is universally used for each project we're on, and even then some people are one different projects), then updating the task scheduler to run each of their created files (not at all desirable, and as far as I'm concerned, unacceptable). If nothing else can be modified or work without interference, I can just using this to run on our company's default project drive letter, and let people worry about reconnecting the others as needed.

I have a task scheduled for any time our VPN client reports a connection, which due to our home networks and/or the connection between us and the VPN servers, could occur multiple times a day (I've had up to 4 or 5 "connection" events trigger my task after the initial login, though I only have to explicitly login the one time), which can cause further interruptions in workflow beyond just the initial VPN login run. I'm willing to accept any solution that uses `NET USE` as long as I can suppress the request for user input if the Windows login password doesn't work, or a shortcut if I can prevent the opening of a file explorer window. Alternative solutions are preferred, but I understand that may not be possible.

I have tested using `DIR //server/foo`, but it timed out for the same reasons that file explorer doesn't display the network drive as "connected" after VPN login is successful.

I've also had mixed results with setting the task scheduler to run my program off of a network connection as opposed to the "connect" event from our VPN client, mostly in that it didn't run reliably, if at all, as I needed to wait until I was connected through the VPN, not just standard internet connection through an ethernet cable. For this, I tried using both methods [here](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/trigger-launch-program-script-connecting-to-specific-network/), but none of the networks that are available after VPN login seemed to trigger the task properly, even though manually triggering the even through Task Scheduler showed the action would run fine. As such, I'm considering this as a failure, but can revisit if no more streamlined solutions are available or I can get a guarantee this method won't trigger as often (preferably only once per login) as watching the VPN client for its connection event.

At this point, I'm stuck with two solutions that have a high potential to interrupt workflow and annoy the user too greatly for me to want to send out as a final solution (a for loop on `NET USE` where drive is disconnected and a batch file to open a shortcut that opens a window front and center), and another solution that I consider to limited in scope and as a last resort. I'll make due if there's not a better way to handle either of the first two, but in the mean time, I would greatly appreciate any help/advice!

Edit:

On a side note, I do expect to have the cmd window pop-up briefly, then close automatically once the operations are done (like it would with the shortcut solution), so some amount of workflow interruption will likely be unavoidable. What I'm considering unacceptable is that I can't minimize it and prevent the user form having to interact with it directly or indirectly to get the cmd or resulting window to close after it takes the active window status from whatever program user was previously in.

Edit 2:

I've posted this query elsewhere with this additional recap to help narrow my request:
As a recap, I'm looking for a solution for refreshing network drive connections that do no rely on Credential Manager, will not require user input if network drive credentials differ from windows login credentials, and will not pop-up a window that requires user to close manually. Brief workflow interruptions resulting from cmd or child-process windows popping up before closing automatically are acceptable, with a preference towards one of the two solution avenues I already have running. Thanks again for any input you may have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lack of a better answer that is viable for our setup (will definitely remember Ben's answer for later, in case I'm able to use it for the lower security profiles), I've decided to go with a more limited scope for my batch file, since I have yet to find any info that will allow me to suppress a file explorer window or request for user input from the cmd window (for password) when attempting to refresh connection to all saved network drives.

Since the one drive that absolutely must be reconnected is, by our guidelines, universally assigned to the same letter (mapping changes depending on the primary project we're on), I've opted for just refreshing this drive as the credentials for this drive will always match the Windows login credentials, and thus won't request user for input if a password is wrong.

I will keep tabs on this question, so that if someone else comes along and has a better solution, I will definitely swap the selected answer to them.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I have 4 mapped drives to reconnect to when I open the VPN and it was a real pain. I have looked for batch file solutions in vain.

My solution is to use a free program called FBackup. I use it anyway for the intended purpose of backing things up, but I noticed that when it opens, it reconnects all of my drives (*including the mapped drives using the VPN to the office*)

So after I connect,  I open FBACKUP. It makes all of the connections for me, then I just shut it down. Job done.

Comment: I really like the simplicity to that, but unfortunately likely not a solution for our situation. IT is pretty restrictive in the group I'm currently working in and doesn't allow non-approved executables to run. That said, I would definitely prefer this solution and will keep it in mind when to test when I'm out of this group on another project.

Answer (score 1):

1 this probably belongs on the site that this site was made to head up against, which I am unsure if I am allowed to reference by name on this site.

That said if it was at this site you probably want topost on Superuser.

That said..

For users with more than one drive mapping you want to store thier credentials used in windows credential manager so that the drives can automatically be mapped without specifying a username and password each time.

That will allow your batch script to run in the background and re-map the drives

Comment: Unfortunately, can't use credential manager. I'm assuming there's a few security reasons for this, but either way IT likely won't enable it. I did forget about that tool, though.
I'll take some time later this evening or tomorrow to post on the other website to see if I get any other hits. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Windows Credential Manager is a built in portion of windows, its enabled by default, and stores the usernames and passwords for things like mapped drives.  while it can be disabled its not a recomended security practice so strange. Thought you were IT, this is usually ths type of thing IT solves, not end-users.

Comment: That said, just check to be sure credential manager isn't available by running the command line interface `Cmdkey /List` if that does not throw an error credential manager is running as expected, and you can use it to add credentials permanently https://ss64.com/nt/cmdkey.html

Comment: Well, I should be more specific, certain parts of cm are disabled (Windows and Certificate Based Credentials), but Generic Credentials are still enabled. I'm pretty sure they don't want people storing their password, especially with my current security level, in any way if at all possible, though couldn't be sure. They're a little finicky and sometimes overly touchy. And for our company, it's not exclusively IT that solves this kind of issue. I'm working on a lot of the project automation stuff atm, so I ended up picking this up as a side task with my background in cs and scripting.

Comment: The windoes credential store is the encrypted repository windows stores passwords in, each user's credential store is seperate from another's and the credentials can't be exported again once added, its a one-way mechanism, per user, per specific thing to access.

Comment: @pmackn also co sider posting in experts-exchange, as they are more open to these sort of open ended questions there

Comment: It's not so much an exporting issue as users retaining access once off a project. Again, my company is finicky about the higher level of clearance due to the clients/projects it has access to, and does its best to limit it to those who have access. The computers set up for just the lower level of clearance may not have those features disabled, and at the moment I am unsure about this. Thanks for the info and tips, though. I'll probably be trying Experts Exchange in the next day or two with the lack of responses my current two posts have received.